# MongoDB (debian) and authentication using mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb

I'm a little confused by the mongo server setup I'm currently trying to set up.
I have a regular debian webserver running appache and mysql. nothing fancy here.
For a project I'm working on I would like to setup a mongodb server.

after installing mongodb I tried to connect via MongoDB Compass and it worked just fine using `mongodb://domain.tld` only.

For obvious reasons I'd like to have a basic user authentication on mentioned server.

here's what I did so far:

```
> use admin
> db.createUser({
    user: "my_username",
    pwd: "my_password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  })
```

and in the `/etc/mongod.conf` i added:

```
security:
    authorization: "enabled"
```

after stopping, deleting /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock and starting again I was still able to connect via `mongodb://domain.tld` and was not asked for authentication.

Am I doing something wrong here or does mongo work on a different concept I'm missing here? Either way, I hope someone is able to help me out here. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What command do you use to run mongodb instance?

Comment: `service mongodb start`

Comment: You haven't made the proper changes or your config file isn't read by the server.